# I'm trying to send a message after 2 persons react to a discord message using my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a battle command for my discord bot where people can fight each other.
This is my current code :

```js
//rng battl command (my whole life has lead up to this and bela cant stop me)
if(message.content.startsWith(`k!battle`)) {
var opponent = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')
if(!opponent) return message.reply('Wait, who were you going to battle again?\nProper command useage: **k!battle <@username>**')
message.channel.send('Mentioned user, you have been challenged to a battle! Do you accept?')
message.channel.send(opponent)

//battle accept/deny
message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};
    
message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 3, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => message.channel.send('Let the battle commence! :KirbyPopcorn:'))
    .catch(collected => {
        message.channel.send(`Battle Expired.`);
    });
}
```

Whenever the two users react to the message, nothing happens, but after the 30 seconds, the Battle Expired text shows up.
Please let me know if you spotted my mistake !

Comment: I think your error is somewhere to do with the filter, you only check the thumbsup for the person who sent a battle request but never check for the `opponent`'s id

Answer (score 0):

As @Sean said in the comments, your `filter` is misconfigured.

You're only allowing the command's author reactions to get through your collector, so you should replace your filter with this one:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => { return reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot; };
```

This one will allow anyone, except bots, to play the game!
I hope this fixes your issue!

PS: You should also lower the collector's `max` to 2 ;)